# Adding values to a newly inserted column in an existing table in PostgreSQL 9.3

Tags: postgresql, psql

created a table named "collegetable":

```
 create table collegetable (stid integer primary key not null,stname
 varchar(50),department varchar(10),dateofjoin date);
```

provided values for each column:[collegetable data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxQSx.png)

inserted a new column in it named "cgpa" and tried to add values for this column in one shot using the code:

```
WITH col(stid, cgpa) as 
(    VALUES((1121,8.01),
            (1131,7.12),
            (1141,9.86))
)        
UPDATE collegetable as colldata
SET cgpa = col.cgpa
FROM col
WHERE colldata.stid = col.stid;
```

and got error :

```
ERROR:operator does not exist:integer=record 
LINE9:where colldata.stid=col.stid; 
HINT:No operator matches the given name and arguement type.you might need to add explicit type casts.
```

pls help in solving.thanks in advance.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the full definition of the tables as `create table` statements, some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**NO screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `with` clause only defines the *names* of the columns, **not** the data types:

```
with col (stid, cgpa) as (
  ...
)
update ...;
```

For details see the [tutorial](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) and the [full reference](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-WITH)

Comment: tried it,by removing the datatype and still it shows an 
ERROR:operator does not exist:integer=record
LINE9:where colldata.stid=col.stid;
and it gave HINT:No operator matches the given name and argueent type.you might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: You have an extra set of parentheses in the CTE: it should be just `VALUES (xxx, yyy), (aaa, bbb), ...` etc.

Comment: fixed it !Thanks a lot Ray O'Donnell